# get max timestamp in azure logic apps expression

Tags: azure-logic-apps

So the dates arrive in string format. 
I am trying to convert to timestamp and finding the largest value/newest timestamp.

I am having a hard time to convert from string to tick and then to timestamp, all the while ending up with only the largest date.

My formula

```
addToTime('0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', div(max( ticks(formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['document_date'])),ticks(formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['requested_date'])),ticks(formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['promised_date'])),ticks(formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['shipment_date'])),ticks(formatDateTime(items('For_each_2')?['posting_date']))),10000000),'second')
```

The error

```
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Update_item' inputs at line '1' and column '3049': 'The template language function 'addToTime' could not create time value with time interval '-701917440' and time unit 'second'. It results in an out of time range value.'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right expression should be like below shows:

```
addToTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z',div(sub(variables('maxticks'), 621355968000000000),10000000),'second')
```

Firstly  I get the max ticks with the below expression from three date:

```
int(max(ticks(formatDateTime(triggerBody()['now'])),ticks(formatDateTime(triggerBody()['yesterday'])),ticks(formatDateTime(triggerBody()['tomorrow']))))
```

Then get the max timestamp:

[image]

[image]